# AJAX doesn't send POST query

Tags: ajax, post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ajaxselectrss(rssurlvar) {
  var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
   ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
   try{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e){
    // Something went wrong
    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

   var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('news');
   ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  }
 }



 //var rssurlvar = $(this).attr("title");
 var queryString = "rurl=" + rssurlvar;
 var urltofile = "rssget.php";
 ajaxRequest.open("POST", urltofile, true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryString.length);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 ajaxRequest.send(queryString); 

}
    $(".rshownews").click(function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {ajaxselectrss($(this).attr("title"))}, 1000);
    });
});
```

The POST query is "undefined" (Firebug).

Comment: This `$(document).ready(function() {` looks like jQuery, is it jQuery? If yes, why don't you use the jQuery Ajax functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - it will standardise the whole XmlHTTPRequest thing across browsers.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rssget.php",
    data: queryString,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#news').html(data);
    }
});
```

(And, BTW, if you `setInterval` in your click handler, you will start a new periodic call to your `ajaxselectrss` function every time the button is clicked.)

Also, your context has changed due to the wrapper function. Try changing your click handler like so:

```
$(".rshownews").click(function() {
  var _this = this;
  window.setInterval(function() {ajaxselectrss($(_this).attr("title"))}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: function ajaxselectrss(rssurlvar) {
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "rssget.php",
   data: "rurl=" + rssurlvar,
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
}

Comment: "POST" here is a string...it can't be undefined. I don't understand.

Comment: Does putting 'rssget.php' in your browser address bar give you anything? You can look at how the data is coming back in Firebug or Chrome developer tools, and/or add an error handler (like the success one) to the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: rurl=undefined.From Firebug - "POST query"

Comment: That would indicate that the rssurlvar you are passing in is undefined. Are you sure the `.rshownews` items have titles?

Comment: A function call be called using the [`call`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/call.html) function - which allows you to set what the 'this' parameter is inside the function. JQuery sets this to be the html DOM element, but in plain javascript it is normally just the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to use jquery anyway ($(document).ready) you could use it's wrapper for simplifying ajax-requests.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post